# TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I got this Error on My Expressjs code which written for Telegram bot
I Hosted this code on CloudVps with Nginx
I used this for Telegram Bot API webhook

It is a Telegram chat bot
set some auto-replies when user input Matches it will send the Autoreply.

Error from Log file

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined
    at app.post (/var/www/hellobot/index.js:22:37)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /var/www/hellobot/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/var/www/hellobot/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
```

Here is My Code

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var Content = require('./blogposts.json');
    var random = Content.blogtext[Math.floor(Math.random() * Content.blogtext.length)];
    const chatId = req.body.message.chat.id;
    const sentMessage = req.body.message.text || req.body.message.sticker.file_id;
    if (sentMessage.match(/start/gi)) {
        axios.post(`${url}${apiToken}/sendMessage`, {
                chat_id: chatId,
                text: 'Hello I am Bot',
            })
            .then((response) => {
                next();
                res.status(200).send(response);
                return res.end();
            }).catch((error) => {
                res.send(error);
            });
    } else if (sentMessage.match(/posts/gi)) {
        axios.post(`${url}${apiToken}/sendMessage`, {
                chat_id: chatId,
                text: random.blogtext,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                next();
                res.status(200).send(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                res.send(error);
            });
    } else {
        axios.post(`${url}${apiToken}/sendMessage`, {
                chat_id: chatId,
                text: 'Sorry answer not found',
            })
            .then((response) => {
                res.status(200).send(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                res.send(error);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Would need to see your entire express file, my guess you haven't included the body parser and set it to process JSON? If not, then `req.body.message.chat.id` won't work because `req.body` won't be an object.

Comment: @jakerella want to see my Full code?

Comment: @jakerella yes having `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Yes, unless we can see the rest of the code it is difficult to understand what may be missing. Also, the line numbers in the error message aren't helpful unless we see the full file so we know what line the error is actually on. Please update the question above